# Jquery filter() only gives me access only to top level elements of response retrieved through ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am retrieving html response using an ajax call and then trying to retrieve a nested element in the response using the following `$(response).filter()`.

This is the page I retrieve, and the element I am trying to filter for:

//ajax call

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "http://www.flipkart.com/search-books?query=jQuery+Cookbook&from=all&searchGroup=all"
}).done(fnSuccess(prod_dts)).fail(fnFail);
```

//fnSuccess

```
var fnSuccess = function(prod_dts) {
return function(response){
           //this returns results
            alert($(response).filter('div.fkart').html());

            // but this does not
            alert($(response).filter('#fk-mainbody-id').html());


  } // endof return
} // endof function
```

The only difference is that `div.fkart` is a direct child of body and `#fk-mainbody-id` is a grandchild.

Isn't filter supposed to drill down all the way through the tree? I am guessing this has something to do with how I wrap the returned response?  How can I access any nested elements this way?

Comment: `find()`...is what you are looking for i guess

Answer (score 0):

Filter is meant to be use to reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test. If you want to drill down use find instead. i.e.

```
var fnSuccess = function(prod_dts) {
  return function(response){
        alert($(response).find('div.fkart').html());
        alert($(response).find('#fk-mainbody-id').html());
  } // endof return
} // endof function
```